# Mount a volume to GCE docker container

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, google-container-registry

I have a very simple docker image that I pushed up to GCR. The docker compose file I use locally looks like:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  matterbridge:
    image: 42wim/matterbridge
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
    - ~/Code/Bot-Relay/matterbridge:/etc/matterbridge
```

I'm trying to create a GCE VM instance with my GCR image, however I'm not sure how to create a volume and pass a file to `/etc/matterbridge`. In my local setup it copies my local `matterbridge` folder and mounts it to the docker container `/etc/matterbridge`

Any idea how I can accomplish this on GCE? Seems simple enough yet I'm stumped. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can,

1. [Mount a host directory as a data volume](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/configuring-options-to-run-containers#mounting_a_host_directory_as_a_data_volume).
2. [Mount tmpfs file system as a data volume](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/configuring-options-to-run-containers#mounting_tmpfs_file_system_as_a_data_volume).
3. [Mount a persistent disk as a data volume](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/configuring-options-to-run-containers#mounting_a_persistent_disk_as_a_data_volume).
4. [Use Volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag) instead of [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/), which is the method you’ve used, based on our preference.

To pass and access a file from a container follow below steps,

1. SSH into the host  GCE VM and upload the file into the VM.
2. To copy a file into a container running on GCE VM, we can make use of below docker command,

   ```
    docker ps   # to view active containers and get the container ID  
    docker cp <file-src-path> container-id:<file-dest-path>   #to copy a file into a container
   ```

3.You can use  below docker command to select working directory for the command to execute into,

```
    docker exec -it -w /<file-dest-path> <container-id> bash
```